# Cache Management

Tags: cache, caching

I would like to know more about Magento Cache Management. What these buttons do??

I would like to know about the functionality of these buttons.

**Flush Mangento Cache**

**Flush Cache Storage**

**Flush Catalog Image Cache**

**Flush Swatch Images Cache**

**Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache**

Answer (score 1):

**Flush Magento Cache**

> This button deals with the main cache items for page display purposes.
>   It can safely be used if you want to refresh your page.
>
> `"Flush Magento Cache"` removes only those entries that Magento
>   reliably tracks as it's own.
>
> Removes all items in the default Magento cache (`var/cache`) and the
>   `var/full_page` cache that have a Magento tag

**Flush Cache Storage**

> This option is a more complete cache flush and includes more items in
>   Magento's cache directory.
>
> `"Flush Cache Storage"` clears everything but might affect other
>   applications if they're using it.
>
> Removes all items in the cache. This is the equivalent of deleting the
>   entire contents of the cache folder on the server.If your system uses
>   an alternate cache location, any cached files used by other
>   applications will be removed.

**Flush Catalog Images Cache**

> The Flush Catalog Images Cache option is just what it says. It deals
>   with the catalog images. If you are changing images on products, and
>   not seeing the new images on your site, you can try flushing this and
>   refreshing your page.
>
> `Flush Catalog Images Cache`button to remove all pregenerated product
>   images files that are stored at: media/catalog/product/cache. If
>   recently uploaded images aren’t visible in the catalog, try flushing
>   the catalog and refreshing your browser

**Flush Swatch Images Cache**

> Swatch images are resized and cached before they are used. Swatch
>   images are stored on the server in the Magento installation directory,
>   at the following location:
>
> `[Magento install directory]/media/catalog/swatches/`
>
> It is used to remove that resized and cached swatch images.

**Flush Javascript/CSS Cache**

> This option involves a lot of the page styling cache and can be
>   flushed when you are making updates. It is not needed regularly, but
>   it is best to do if you want to see any recent changes.
>
> `Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache` button to remove the Themes JavaScript
>   and CSS files combined to one file from the cache. If recent changes
>   to the style sheet or JavaScript aren’t visible in the store, try
>   flushing the JavaScript/CSS cache and refreshing your browser.

Hope this make sense

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/system-operations/cache-clear.html

> ### Flush Magento Cache
>
> Removes all items in the default Magento cache (var/cache), according
>   to their associated Magento tags.
>
> ### Flush Cache Storage
>
> Removes all items from the cache, regardless of Magento tag. If your
>   system uses an alternate cache location, any cached files used by
>   other applications are removed in the process.
>
> ### Flush Catalog Images Cache
>
> Removes all automatically resized and watermarked catalog images that
>   are stored at: media/catalog/product/cache.
>
> If recently uploaded images aren't reflected in the catalog, try
>   flushing the catalog and refreshing your browser.
>
> ### Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache
>
> Removes the merged copy of JavaScript and CSS files from the cache. If
>   recent changes to the style sheet or JavaScript aren't reflected in
>   the store, try flushing the JavaScript/CSS cache and refreshing your
>   browser.
>
> ### Flush Swatch Images Cache
>
> Removes pregenerated swatch image files.